# iso download fails Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS 32bit

Tags: release-management

I have tried downloading Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS 32bit but it fails at 156.790kb image file at start of download says 645mb it will only download 156.790kb then finishes. where can I download this image to receive the full download? I have tried to download it in different browsers same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Open [this](http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/DVDs/ubuntu/12.04.1/release/ubuntu-12.04.1-server-i386.metalink) as a text file.

You will able to see all links. Maybe you will be able to use them. Try each one, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I can download the Ubuntu Server 12.04.1-i386 image just fine, but it appears to be a bad ISO. No matter which computer I use to download the image I am unable to read it. I am also unable to find a link back to the previous version ISO (12.04 without the .1).

I've tried this using Mac OS X v10.8.2 (Mt Lion), Windows XP SP2, and VMware ESX.

UPDATE: Also, the amd64 appears to have the same problem. Perhaps it's the mirror that the web site is pointing me to by default that has the bad images? I guess I'll start trying links from Xiokang's response...

UPDATE: Doesn't seem to matter which mirror I use. The MD5 checksum verifies that the image I'm downloading matches what Canonical thinks I should have. However, I still can't do anything useful with the images, nor can VMware read it.

Checksums:

- ubuntu-12.04.1-server-i386.iso  = 3daaa312833a7da1e85e2a02787e4b66
- ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64.iso = a8c667e871f48f3a662f3fbf1c3ddb17

These match what Canonical has listed [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/MD5SUMS).

SOLUTION: Ok, apparently these images are SUPPOSED to be broken, as they are using some kind of hybrid multi session layout or something. OS X is not able to verify or read these images without extra help from some shell commands. Also, VMware, when using EFI mode, will not be able to boot from the images as well. Apparently these images are intended for applications (like Roxio Toast) to burn directly to physical optical media. Hence why they have the unusual hybrid configuration, which works fine when being read from a CD. Follow the instructions for creating a USB thumbstick in order to use the images on a Mac. For VMware, make sure that your ESX virtual machine is set to use BIOS rather than EFI.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you can download torrents which is the preferred way to download big files then use this

http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

if you don't want torrents. Then take my advice: Never download big files using the default downloader of the browser, they are so bad, do not support stopping and resuming, and you will often end up with a corrupted image. Use an independent download manager. If you're on windows use [FDM](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/), if you're on Linux download [uget](http://ugetdm.com/).